# Simple integration testing using bash with CMake and CTest?

Tags: bash, cmake, integration-testing, ctest

I have a C++ CMake project where I use Google Test for unit testing and I'm happy with the XML reports produced using `ctest -T Test`. Now I would like to implement couple of integration tests that run specific application scenarios and expect a specific output e.g. running a C++ executable with default values should produce a specific output e.g. the following `integration_test_01.sh` bash shell would be such a test:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ./my_algorithm > out && grep "mse\=1\.2345e\-6" out 
 if [ $? == 0 ]; then
     echo "integration test succeeded"
 else
     echo "integration test failed" >&2
 fi
 rm out | cat
```

Is there a way to integrate such test with CMake or CTest and maybe even get some XML output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CMake and CTest you can add a test for `my_algorithm` in the following way:

```
add_executable(my_algorithm ...)
add_test(NAME integration_test_01 COMMAND my_algorithm)
set_tests_properties(integration_test_01 
    PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "mse\\=1\\.2345e\\-6")
```

The output of the command `my_algorithm` will be checked against the specified regular expression and if the output does not match the test will fail.

When you run tests with `ctest -T Test` the generated XML report will contain the actual output of the command nested in a `<Measurement>` tag.